# Можно ли поднять регистр слова с помощью (найти-заменить) Regex в Datacol?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я пользуюсь парсингом **Datacol**.
При сборе данных в нем есть механизм для поиска и замены текста. Если установлен чекбокс **Regex**, поле **"Старое значение"** работает как регулярное выражение. (см.скриншот)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя задача отформатировать ссылку.

```
https://mysite.com/media-photo-video/123456
```

1. удалить домен;
2. удалить все, что после последнего слеша(**/**).
3. заменить знаки (**-**) и (**_**) на пробел.
4. поднять регистр первых букв в каждом слове.

Результат должен быть следующим:

```
Media Photo Video
```

Первых три задачи я выполняю без проблем, но никак не могу поднять регистр.

Как это можно сделать в моем случае? И можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен благодаря [bestweb4u.net](https://bestweb4u.net/work-with-string-and-dyn-plugin-in-datacol) с помощью динамического плагина:

`s = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s);`